# Push content from Contentful to postgresql on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, api, heroku, contentful

I have these categories and as I am adding more items to each one that will include: image, description, and few other text fields. I want them get pushed to my database (postgresql) on Heroku so then my mobile app can pull these later and be updated.

Is there a way to push contents from Contentful to a database on Heroku? I only see a way to pull contents from Contentful not push.

Answer (score 0):

Heyooo Contentful DevRel here.

To "push" data into another system Contentful provides [webhooks](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/). These are HTTP requests that are made when you create/update an entry. Their payload includes information about the updated entry.

However, to feed your database you'd need some logic in between Contentful and your database. The way I'd approach this is to set up an HTTP endpoint (i usually go with serverless functions) that is able to modify transform your database. This endpoint can then retrieve the information of updated Contentful content and modify your database.

Hope that helps. :)